# Requests not going through the proxy

Tags: proxy, burp

Heyo everyone !

I'm trying to reverse ingeneer an API using Burp. The problem is that I can't see any of the requests made by the software using the said API while I can see the requests made from Spotify, Discord, etc... I set the proxy parametter of windows to localhost:8080 and burp to listen to *:8080

Do you have any idea on what could make that happen ? I've been exploring the web I have yet to see an answer to my problem...

*If I can improve by any means this question, to hesitate to let me know !*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called SSL Pining and it's a method to protect against Man-in-middle type of attacks. It's very effective !

---

You can learn more about it through these articles:

https://sslmagic.com/blog/introduction-to-ssl-pinning/

https://medium.com/@anuj.rai2489/ssl-pinning-254fa8ca2109

https://www.indusface.com/learning/what-is-ssl-pinning-a-quick-walk-through/

---

*I'm not related to any of these articles by any means. I just find them useful to understand SSL Pining*